# PHP calculating hours

Tags: php, date, strtotime

Something is not working properly with the following code and I am going mad trying to understand why it is not calculating correctly:

```
$hours = date('H:i' , strtotime('03:00') - strtotime('02:00'));

echo $hours;
```

Result: `02:00`

Expected Result: `01:00`

Could anyone help me guessing what is going wrong?

[02:00 as the result](https://3v4l.org/EIZ4s)

Comment: But when try to run your code its shows `01:00`

Comment: @Albzi thank you for your answer. When I use only one strtotime, it calculated correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want something like this instead:

```
$hours = date('H:i' , strtotime('03:00 - 02:00'));
```

Or even:

```
$hours = date('H:i' , strtotime('03:00 - 2 hours'));
```

This will print `01:00`.

https://3v4l.org/on4JH

Comment: @LifeTimeProgrammer Look at this link: https://3v4l.org/EIZ4s It shows OP's behavior he doesn't want.

Comment: yes i looked up. but when my `local server` its working as well as your code also .

Comment: That's PHP for you haha @LifeTimeProgrammer

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @rjdown Nice catch. Time/date is a pain!

Comment: No worries, hope it helped! @AlexandreRibeiro

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object to accomplish it:

```
$date1 = new DateTime('03:00');
$date2 = new DateTime('02:00');
$dateInterval = $date1->diff($date2);

echo $dateInterval->format('%H:%S'); // result would be 01:00
```